# Set up git for Jekyll on GitHub Pages

Tags: git, github, jekyll, github-pages

I am using Jekyll for static site generation. So currently I have a master branch inside _site folder which I push after every build.

But this means that I cannot do any changes from any other system as I don't have the source of the project. I looked around and found that people have created another branch where their entire project is lying.I am not very good with git branching concept.

Suggest some way to push the source too, so that I can make changes to my project from anywhere.

**--EDIT---**

I am hosting the site not a specific project in github that is present in username.guthub.io/project using gh-pages.

Comment: why not branch the entire project, then only push the contents of _site to your server?

Comment: i am not using any external server for my project.I want to use github as the server only.

Answer (score 1):

Check: https://help.github.com/articles/using-jekyll-with-pages/#using-jekyll

You don't want to push your `_site` folder to github. Github generates the jekyll site automatically when the project files are on `gh-pages` branch.

1. On your local machine, create a git repo in the root directory of your project (not inside the `_site` folder).
2. You need a branch named `gh-pages` (locally and remotely)
3. Push to github all your files except the `_site` folder (when you are on `gh-pages` branch)
4. Github will automatically generate your site and you will be able to see it online at `username.github.io/projectname`

You will have your source on github and every time you push some changes to this `gh-pages` branch, your page will be rebuild and update by github